# Given that $z = (1+ bi) ^{2}$, find the exact value of b if $arg z = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and b is real and positive.

Tags: complex-numbers

Essentially the title.

This is a homework problem, and I tried to do it by considering it as a $1 ,\sqrt{3},2$ triangle as the angle is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and thus $b$ would be $\sqrt{3}$. However, the answer section in the back of the textbook says the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and I am confused why this is the case.

Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot the square.

Comment: With $z=1-b^2+2ib$ then $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{3}=\dfrac{1-b^2}{2b}$

Comment: @Randall I couldn't figure exactly how to get it to factor in such that it would lead to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Can you explain?

Comment: @Nosrati Oh, alright, I did not consider that it could essentially still be a + bi form after expanded. Thanks.

Comment: See Nosrati's comment then express it as a polynomial and use the quadratic formula to solve.

Comment: @LiamWilson  CyclotomicField's answer explains what I was getting at:  because of the square you have to halve the angle first.

Answer (score 1):

From the polar form of a complex number we know that squaring will square the radius and double the angle. This gives us $\arg (1+bi) =\frac{\pi}{6}$ and since we can calculate $|1+bi| = \sqrt{1 + b^2}$ we now have the argument and the radius.

Then by converting back to cartesian coordinates we find that $x=1=\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})\sqrt{1 + b^2}$ and it follows that $$b = \sqrt{\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})^{-2}-1}$$ from here simply substitute $\cos{\frac{\pi}{6}}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and we finally have that $b =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ as the book suggests.